# Cantor intersection theorem where sets aren't necessarily closed

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I came across a problem that states that given $(X,d)$ a complete metric space and a decreasing sequence of non-empty bounded sets $A_n \subseteq X$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty } diam(A_n) = 0$ then there is some $x \in X: A_n \subseteq B_x(r)$ for some set $A_n$ in the sequence and for every ball centered at $x$.

I know that Cantor's intersection theorem states that if the sets $A_n$ are closed then $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n = \{x\}$. But here the sets aren't closed, so why is it that $A_n \subseteq B_x(r)$?

Comment: The intersection of balls centered at $x$ is $\{x\}$, so how can one $A_n$ be contained in all of them?

Comment: One $A_n$ is contained in any ball centered at $x$ (for some particular $x$ and every $r$). Not in their intersection

Comment: Show that the closures $\overline{A_n}$ meet the conditions of Cantor's intersection theorem and take $x\in\bigcap_n \overline{A_n}$.  Then $x$ is a limit point of $A_n$ for all $n$.  So given $r>0$ the neighborhood $B(x,r)$ intersects $A_n$ for all $n$.  Now find a sufficiently large $n$ so that $A_n$ is completely contained in $B(x,r)$.  This can be done since $\operatorname{diam}(A_n)\to 0$.

Comment: @JohnDoe In addition to closedness, one requires compactness in Cantor Intersection Theorem. Boundedness does not suffice to conclude total boundedness or precompactness in non-finite dimensional spaces.

Comment: So formalizing your idea, since $diam(A_n) \to 0$ there is some $n_0$ such that for all $n > n_0, d(x_n, x) \to 0$ for every $x_n \in A_n$. Then $A_n \subseteq B(x,r)$. Is that correct @John Doe?

Comment: @SaimFaigol: I got the order a little bit wrong.  Start by choosing large enough $n$ such that $\operatorname{diam}(A_n)<r/2$.  Then take $y\in A_n\cap B(x,r/2)$ (which is non-empty).  Then by the triangle inquality $d(z,x)<r$ for all $z\in A_n$.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron:  Cantor's intersection theorem in a complete metric space uses a Cauchy sequence.  No compactness necessary.

Comment: @JohnDoe I see. I am not totally familiar with it. Can you state it as a proper theorem and perhaps a reference?

Comment: @JohnDoe Thanks for your help! I get that $B(x,r) \cap \overline{A_n} \neq \emptyset \ \forall n$ but why is it that $B(x,r) \cap A_n \neq \emptyset \ \forall n$?

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem variant in complete metric spaces

Comment: @SaimFaigol: $x\in\overline{A_n}$, so $x$ is a limit point of $A_n$, so every neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A_n$.

Comment: Oh right, I don't know how I missed that. Thanks again!

Comment: @SaimFaigol Thanks. I never really did encounter this variant as a "theorem". But it's good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need even to bring in the big guns of the Cantor intersection theorem.

Just choose an $x_n\in A_n$. When $m > n, x_m \in A_m \subseteq A_n$, and therefore $d(x_m, x_n) \le \text{diam}(A_n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, so the sequence is Cauchy and has limit $x$.

Since $x \in \overline{A_n}$ for all $n$, for any $r > 0$, when $n$ is large enough that $\text{diam}(A_n) < r$, it must be that $A_n \subseteq B_x(r)$.